# Disable button in Ember with return value of function

Tags: ember.js

I've been trying to create an Ember Component with the latest version on Ember. Here is the part of the component I'm having trouble with though:

//app/templates/components/page-r.hbs

```
<div class="pager-container">
  {{#each range as |page|}}
    <button type="button" disabled={{isCurrentPage(page)}}>{{page}}</button>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

//app/components/page-r.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const PageR = Ember.Component.extend({
  settings: Ember.computed('params.[]', function() {
    return this.get('params')[0];
  }),
  range: [4,5,6],
  currentPage: 1,
  isCurrentPage(pageIndex) {
    return this.currentPage === pageIndex;
  },
});

PageR.reopenClass({
  positionalParams: 'settings'
});

export default PageR;
```

There is more to the component than that, but my question is this: 
**Is it possible to make the disabled attribute update based off of the result of an action like I'm trying to do? If so, how?** 
The above code doesn't even compile, but I've tried a number of variations and haven't gotten any of them to work. I can get the disabled property to work based off a pure boolean value, but can't figure out how to get this to execute the function and utilize the boolean value that is returned from it to fuel the disabled attribute. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another component to create the computed property.

```
// app/templates/components/page-r.hbs
<div class="pager-container">
  {{#each range as |page|}}
    {{page-button page=page currentPage=currentPage}}
  {{/each}}
</div>

// app/templates/components/page-button.hbs
<button type="button" disabled={{isCurrentPage}}>{{page}}</button>

// app/components/page-r.js

import Ember from 'ember';

const { computed } = Ember;

const PageR = Ember.Component.extend({
  settings: computed('params.[]', function() {
    return this.get('params')[0];
  }),
  range: [4,5,6],
  currentPage: 1
});

PageR.reopenClass({
  positionalParams: 'settings'
});

export default PageR;

// app/components/page-button.js

import Ember from "ember";

const { computed } = Ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  isCurrentPage: computed('currentPage', 'page', function() {
    return this.get('currentPage') === this.get('page');
  }),
});
```